# PHP / MySQL: Print specific value from array (query result) based on its ID

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, associative-array

I use the following PHP lines to query data from a MySQL table. 
I want to store the query results in an array and then later on the same page print specific values from this array based on their ID.

I am new to PHP and hope someone can help me with an explanation on what I am doing wrong or missing here. I am assuming I create the array wrongly.

**My PHP (relevant part, variables are defined earlier on this page):**

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, $col FROM $table ORDER BY id");
$rows = array();

if($result)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        print_r($row);
    } 
}
var_dump($rows);
```

**My current array (when printed as above):**

```
Array ( [0] => testid1 [id] => testid1 [1] => testval1 [en] => testval1 ) Array ( [0] => testid2 [id] => testid2 [1] => testval2 [en] => testval2 ) Array ( [0] => testid3 [id] => testid3 [1] => testval3 [en] => testval3 ) array(0) { }
```

**Example:**
E.g. I want to print the value for the item with ID = "**testid2**" from this array. 
In this case the printed value should be "**testval2**".

Many thanks in advance, 
*Mike*

Comment: `print_r` doesn't create an array, it outputs all values in an array or object. Change to `$rows[] = $row;` inside your `while`. ... or simply use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php.

Comment: @user3783243: Thank you. Do you have an example or a link to show me how to create the array and how to print a value from it ?

Comment: `print_r($set['1']);` ? `print_r($set['1']['id']);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your data as:

```
for
(
    $set = array(); 
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
    // use value of `id` as the key in your `$set`
    $set[$row['id']] = $row
);
print_r($set);

// later:
$id = 1;
echo $set[$id]['en'];
// or
echo $set[$id][$lang];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `fetch_all()` and then column search

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, $lang FROM $table ORDER BY id");
$set = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$key = array_search('testid2', array_column($set, 'id'));

echo $set[$key]['en'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) with [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to convert the query output (in rows and columns) to key-value format (key being the `id`, and value being the `en` column):

```
// $set array is populated using fetch_assoc
// create a new array using $set
$modified_set = array_combine(array_column($set, 'id'), 
                              array_column($set, 'en'));

// Now, you can access the en value for a specific id like this:
// eg: for id = testid2
echo $modified_set['testid2']; // will display testval2
```